# Finiteness of improper integral given limit of function

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

EDITED text:

I was trying to get an answer to a slightly different problem, but I posted it here in greater generality, and made a slight mistake in it too. The question actually is, given that $f$ is continuously differentiable, and that $lim_{|t|\to \infty}f'(t)\exp(-t^2) = 0$ is $\int _{-\infty}^{+\infty}f'(t)\exp(-t^2)dt$ finite?

ORIGINAL text:
Given $lim_{|t|\to \infty}f(t) = 0$ and that $f$ is continuously differentiable can we say $\int _{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)dt$ is finite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following function:

If $|t|\leq\frac\pi2$$$f(t) = \cos(t) + 2^{\frac{-1}4} $$

Otherwise
$$f(t) = \frac1{|t| + 2^{\frac14} - \frac\pi2}$$

Why is this a counter example? Well, its easy to show this function is continuously differentiable at all points besides $t=\pm\frac\pi2$, and at these points, you can show through some algebra that this function is continuous and differentiable.

But, because of the nature of $\frac1t$, this function will have an infinite integral.

Now your question asks for $f'(t)e^{-t^2}$. We can set the function I found equal to this expression to find the actual $f$ that violates your condition.

## Edit

My original example was $f'(t)\exp(-t^2) = \frac1{|t|+1}$, which happens to also be sufficient to disprove OP's question.

Comment: It's almost a perfect example, but this function isn't differentiable at $t=0$. Of course, this is not important for the divergence of the imporper integral at all. But technically speaking, it doesn't satisfy the OP's requirements.

Comment: edited the question a bit.

Comment: @RushabhMehta it still doesn't quite work, but the question changed

Comment: That's funny -- now, after the question has been updated, you can go back to your original example! :-) For $f(t)$ to be continuously differentiable, $f'(t)$ and $f'(t)e^{-t^2}$ only need to be continuous.

Comment: I hate life right now loll, I spent like 10 minutes trying to redesign that function to work. Whatever